# ValueError when reading excel from sharepoint to python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sharepoint

I am trying to read an excel file from sharepoint to python.

Q1: There are two URLs for the file. If I directly copy the link of the file, I get:

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/project/letters-numbers?e=lettersnumbers
```

If I click into folders from the webpage one after another, until I click and open the excel file, the URL now is:

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/project/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=letters-numbers&file=Table.xlsx&action=default&mobileredirect=true
```

Which one should I use?

Q2: My code below:

```
import pandas as pd
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File

URL = "https://company.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/project/letters-numbers?e=lettersnumbers"
USERNAME = "abc@a.com"
PASSWORD = "abcd"

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(URL)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(USERNAME, PASSWORD):
    ctx = ClientContext(URL, ctx_auth)
    web = ctx.web
    ctx.load(web)
    ctx.execute_query()
    print("Authentication successful")
else:
    print(ctx_auth.get_last_error())

response = File.open_binary(ctx, URL)
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0)
df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheet_name="Sheet2")
```

It works until the `pd.read_excel()`, where I get ValueError.

```
ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.
```

I don't know where it went wrong and if there will be further problems with loading. It will be highly appreciated if someone could warn me of the problems or leave an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried different URLs (and how to obtain them), and received different binary files. They are either a line of code status (like 403) or warning, or something that looks like a header. So I believe the problem is the URL format.

[Here](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/issues/208#issuecomment-643818791) (github.com/vgrem) I found the answer.

It basically says that for `ClientContext` you need an absolute URL,

```
URL = "https://company.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/project"
```

And for `File` you need a relative path, but with overlap with the URL:

```
RELATIVE_PATH = "/sites/project/Shared%20Documents/Folder/Table.xlsx"
```

The `RELATIVE_PATH` can be found like this:

1. Go to the folder of the file in Teams (or on the webpage).
2. Choose the file, `Open in app` (Excel).
3. In Excel, `File` -> `Property`, copy the path and **adapt to the above format**.
4. Replace `Space` with `"%20"`.

```
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(URL)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(USERNAME, PASSWORD):
    ctx = ClientContext(URL, ctx_auth)
    web = ctx.web
    ctx.load(web)
    ctx.execute_query()
    print("Authentication successful")
else:
    print(ctx_auth.get_last_error())

response = File.open_binary(ctx, RELATIVE_PATH)
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0)
df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheet_name='Sheet2')
```

If the `sheet_name` is not specified and the original `.xlsx` has multiple sheets, the `pd.read_excel()` will generate warnings and the `df` here is actually a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the pandas documentation for ‘read_excel’ (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), you’ll see that there is an ‘engine’ parameter.

Try the different options and see which one works, since your error is saying that an engine has to be specified manually.

If this is correct, in the future, take the error messages literally and check the documentation

Comment: I've tried all options. With 'xlrd': `xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\r\n<!DOCT'`. The other engines all give: `zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`.